# Does rabbitmq maintain a binding history to a exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to analyze the customers who are consuming the data from the topic exchange.
Is there a way to get the history of binding to this topic exchange in the last 30 days or max available time limit?

Suppose since last 1 week 20 services consumed from the topic.
Then I can get these 20 services from binding history.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, RabbitMQ does not support this feature out of the box, but you may be able to implement this yourself using the Event Exchange:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/event-exchange.html